# Dynamic Phone Numbers / Affiliate Module

Tags: 7

I'm working on a site that has a requirement to have a dynamic phone number in the header.

This number changes when visitors come from another site to the site I' working on.

I've looked around and done plenty of searching on Google but can't find any existing modules that do this, or something similar.

Does anyone know of an existing module for this? or a way I can do it?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: For highly specific needs like this, there often is no off-the-shelf module.  What kind of approaches were you considering to satisfy this requirement?

Comment: Well I was kind of hoping that there might be something out there already, or more likely that someone has already done something similar.

I guess I'm going to have to write a new module for this - I've already briefly looked into doing this, any tips or resources for writing your first module?

Comment: You should take a look at the Module Builder  (http://drupal.org/project/module_builder). The Module developer's guide is also a good starting point (http://drupal.org/developing/modules).